# Magento don't show subtotals, discount, shipping in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm almost finishing my store, but there's a problem who's blowing my mind. I use magento 1.9.3.1 and Porto theme 2.4.4

My checkout don't show information about subtotals, discount, shipping... everything works fine, all the payment methods process the cost correctly, but it's not showing in checkout. I'm uploading some images to show you.

1) in cart

[image: cart]

2) in normal checkout

[image: normal]

3) in one page checkout

[image: onepage]

i already tried to disable my theme and use magento rwd, but the problem persists. Someone can help me? The address is [lojateste.veganis.com.br](http://lojateste.veganis.com.br)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [Khushbu_sipl](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/38642/khushbu-sipl) who gave me a light, i remembered i turned off the module Mage_Tax, after enable it, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

kindly try this -
[image] 
In the admin Panel go to System->configuration->Sales->Tax
    Below is the Image to show labels.

Comment: thank you for try to help @Khushbu-sipl , but my tax configuration section is the same you show me now.